# How to integrate django with kibana

Tags: django

I am learning Django 2 and need integrate django with kibana, and configurate setting for send logs to kibana. If anyone knows integrations, please share with me.

Comment: Have you tried Googling? Google yields several hits for this

Answer (score 1):

I prefer keeping such integration separate from application logic, even if it is possibble.

Django writes its logs to a log-file like it normally does.

A completely separate program like logstash, reads the logfile and pushes it to elasticsearch for indexing and later showing on kibana dashboard.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you, I have question, logstash read the log-file in real time?

Comment: the frequency is configurable. However a buffered read is advisable.
you would not want to let the logging program hog the resources all the time on production. So usually, it is configured to push the logs every X seconds / minutes.